# HtmlAgilityPack troupbles with XPATH

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a piece of html that I'm trying to parse using HtmlAgilityPack. Here's the piece of the code I'm interested in (sorry for using a picture, but it's cleaner and shows the point I want more clearly):

[image]

What I'm trying to do is very simple, but I can't figure it out. What I want is to select the `div` with `id = content` that is highlighted in the image. To do this with HtmlAgilitypack in c# I'm using:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); //creating HtmlAgilityPack document
doc.LoadHtml(htmlstring); //loading html

var content = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='content']"); //running XPATH
```

The problem is that the last instruction selects the div I mention above, but it's incomplete.  Instead of containing all the children shown in the image it only contains one child, the first `div` with `id = item`
The same piece of XPATH when run through Chrome with XPTAH Helper selects the correct div with all its children.
I don't understand if I'm using HtmlAgilityPack incorrectly or if my XPATH expression is incorrect, can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use the `content` variable? What you have shown us so far looks fine.

Comment: @JLRishe: very simply, when I examine content.InnerHtml, it only contains the the first child (the first div with id = item) instead of all of them. Further querying on the content node confirms this, showing there is only one item. Maybe my question is badly phrased, the xpath does indeed select the wanted div, but with only the first child inside instead of all of them. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: Is there some place on the internet where we could view this page to see if there's anything odd with it? One thing that stands out is that you have a lot of elements with the same `id`, which is not valid in HTML. I doubt that's the cause of the issue, but you never know...

Comment: @JLRishe: I've pasted the full source here: http://pastebin.com/Zxj4zkR4  I noticed the multiple IDs too, unfortunately I'm not the one who created the page, can't do much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've got some messed up HTML to deal with there. Every one of those `item`s contains two malformed `<a>` tags.

One is missing its `>` at the end of its start tag:

```
<div id="covershot"><a href="http://www.cineblog01.tv/the-thirteenth-tale-subita-2013/" target="_self" <p><img src="http://www.locandinebest.net/imgk/The_Thirteenth_Tale_2013.jpg"></p>
```

and the other stops dead after `<a class="` and has no closing tag.

```
<td><div><a class="<div class="fblike_button" style="margin: 10px 0;"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cineblog01.tv%2Fthe-thirteenth-tale-subita-2013%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=150&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:20px"></iframe></div> </div> </td>
```

I'm guessing that's causing some problems for the parser.  Have you tried selecting the `wrapper` or `contentwrapper` `div`s to see if it's putting the missing `div`s inside them?

You might try to fix these problems with some string replacement to see if that gets it to parse correctly:

```
htmlstring = htmlstring.Replace("target=\"_self\" <", "target=\"_self\" ><")
                       .Replace("<a class=\"<", "<");
```

Comment: Damn, I hadn't noticed that, I wonder how the hell the browser is even able to render that. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try with the string replacement, will report back. Unfortunately I can't change the html in question, so I have to try and fix it in code.

Comment: Sorry, forgotten about this question, that was exactly the problem, answer accepted.